# Why Cygwin installtion folder is taking 5 gb in my system? How can I reduce it?

Tags: windows, cygwin, storage

I have Cygwin installed within Windows 10, on a non-OS partition, and might have installed unwanted packages during setup periodically for updates.

I only need it for C/C++ Compiler library, so I just need to know which ones are safe to remove *(a [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54043012/cygwin-folder-too-large-taking-up-10gb-is-there-a-way-to-reduce-this-without) thread exists, but doesn't say which packages are essential and which to remove)*:

- ```
  $ du

    427M  - /bin
    0 KB  - /dev
    4.5M  - /etc
    166K  - /home
    3.4G  - /lib
    696K  - /sbin
    4.0K  - /tmp
    4.4G  - /usr
    1010K - /var
  ```
- **`cygdrive` returns 318 package names:**

  ```
  - autorebase
  - adwaita-icon-theme
  - alternatives
  - at-spi2-core
  - base-cygwin
  - base-files
  - bash
  - binutils
  - bzip2
  - ca-certificates
  - chere
  - clang
  - clang-debuginfo
  - cmake
  - cmake-gui
  - compiler-rt
  - coreutils
  - crypto-policies
  - csih
  - cygrunsrv
  - cygutils
  - cygwin
  - cygwin-debuginfo
  - cygwin-devel
  - dash
  - dconf-service
  - dejavu-fonts
  - desktop-file-utils
  - diffutils
  - dri-drivers
  - editrights
  - file
  - findutils
  - fontconfig
  - gamin
  - gawk
  - gcc-core
  - gcc-g++
  - gdb
  - gdb-debuginfo
  - gdk-pixbuf2.0-svg
  - getent
  - git
  - glib2.0-networking
  - gnu-free-fonts
  - grep
  - groff
  - gsettings-desktop-schemas
  - gtk-update-icon-cache
  - gzip
  - hicolor-icon-theme
  - hostname
  - info
  - ipc-utils
  - less
  - libarchive13
  - libargp
  - libatk-bridge2.0_0
  - libatk1.0_0
  - libatomic1
  - libatspi0
  - libattr1
  - libblkid1
  - libboost-devel
  - libboost_atomic1.66
  - libboost_chrono1.66
  - libboost_container1.66
  - libboost_context1.66
  - libboost_coroutine1.66
  - libboost_date_time1.66
  - libboost_filesystem1.66
  - libboost_graph1.66
  - libboost_iostreams1.66
  - libboost_locale1.66
  - libboost_log1.66
  - libboost_math1.66
  - libboost_program_options1.66
  - libboost_random1.66
  - libboost_regex1.66
  - libboost_serialization1.66
  - libboost_signals1.66
  - libboost_stacktrace1.66
  - libboost_system1.66
  - libboost_test1.66
  - libboost_thread1.66
  - libboost_timer1.66
  - libboost_type_erasure1.66
  - libboost_wave1.66
  - libbrotlicommon1
  - libbrotlidec1
  - libbz2_1
  - libc++-devel
  - libc++1
  - libc++abi-devel
  - libc++abi1
  - libcairo2
  - libclang8
  - libcom_err2
  - libcroco0.6_3
  - libcrypt2
  - libcurl4
  - libdatrie1
  - libdb5.3
  - libdbus1_3
  - libdeflate0
  - libedit0
  - libepoxy0
  - libexpat1
  - libfam0
  - libfdisk1
  - libffi6
  - libffi8
  - libfido2
  - libfontconfig-common
  - libfontconfig1
  - libfreetype6
  - libfribidi0
  - libgc1
  - libgcc1
  - libgcrypt20
  - libgdbm6
  - libgdbm_compat4
  - libgdk_pixbuf2.0_0
  - libGL1
  - libglapi0
  - libglib2.0_0
  - libgmp10
  - libgnutls30
  - libgomp1
  - libgpg-error0
  - libgraphite2_3
  - libgsasl-common
  - libgsasl18
  - libgssapi_krb5_2
  - libgtk3_0
  - libguile3.0_1
  - libharfbuzz0
  - libhogweed4
  - libICE6
  - libiconv
  - libiconv2
  - libicu-devel
  - libicu61
  - libicu72
  - libidn12
  - libidn2_0
  - libimagequant0
  - libintl8
  - libisl23
  - libjasper4
  - libjbig2
  - libjpeg8
  - libjson-glib1.0_0
  - libjsoncpp25
  - libk5crypto3
  - libkrb5_3
  - libkrb5support0
  - liblcms2_2
  - libllvm8
  - liblz4_1
  - liblzma5
  - liblzo2_2
  - libmpc3
  - libmpfr6
  - libncursesw10
  - libnettle6
  - libnghttp2_14
  - libntlm0
  - libopenldap2
  - libopenldap2_4_2
  - libp11-kit0
  - libpango1.0_0
  - libpcre1
  - libpcre2_16_0
  - libpcre2_8_0
  - libpipeline1
  - libpixman1_0
  - libpkgconf4
  - libpng16
  - libpolly8
  - libpopt-common
  - libpopt0
  - libproxy1
  - libpsl5
  - libQt5Core5
  - libQt5Gui5
  - libquadmath0
  - libraqm0
  - libreadline7
  - librest0.7_0
  - librhash0
  - librsvg2_2
  - libsasl2_3
  - libsigsegv2
  - libSM6
  - libsmartcols1
  - libsoup-gnome2.4_1
  - libsoup2.4_1
  - libsource-highlight-common
  - libsource-highlight4
  - libsqlite3_0
  - libssh2_1
  - libssl1.0
  - libssl1.1
  - libstdc++6
  - libtasn1_6
  - libthai0
  - libtiff6
  - libunistring2
  - libunistring5
  - libunwind-devel
  - libunwind1
  - libuuid-devel
  - libuuid1
  - libuv1
  - libwebp7
  - libwebpdemux2
  - libwebpmux3
  - libX11-xcb1
  - libX11_6
  - libXau6
  - libxcb-glx0
  - libxcb-icccm4
  - libxcb-image0
  - libxcb-keysyms1
  - libxcb-randr0
  - libxcb-render-util0
  - libxcb-render0
  - libxcb-shape0
  - libxcb-shm0
  - libxcb-sync1
  - libxcb-util1
  - libxcb-xfixes0
  - libxcb-xinerama0
  - libxcb-xkb1
  - libxcb1
  - libXcomposite1
  - libXcursor1
  - libXdamage1
  - libXdmcp6
  - libXext6
  - libXfixes3
  - libXft2
  - libXi6
  - libXinerama1
  - libxkbcommon0
  - libxml2
  - libXrandr2
  - libXrender1
  - libXtst6
  - libxxhash0
  - libzstd1
  - login
  - make
  - man-db
  - mintty
  - ncurses
  - openssh
  - openssl
  - p11-kit
  - p11-kit-trust
  - perl-Error
  - perl-TermReadKey
  - perl_autorebase
  - perl_base
  - pkg-config
  - pkgconf
  - publicsuffix-list-dafsa
  - python2
  - python27
  - python27-pip
  - python27-setuptools
  - python3
  - python39
  - python39-babel
  - python39-chardet
  - python39-docutils
  - python39-idna
  - python39-imagesize
  - python39-imaging
  - python39-iniconfig
  - python39-jinja2
  - python39-markupsafe
  - python39-olefile
  - python39-packaging
  - python39-pip
  - python39-platformdirs
  - python39-pluggy
  - python39-pygments
  - python39-pyparsing
  - python39-pytest
  - python39-requests
  - python39-setuptools
  - python39-six
  - python39-snowballstemmer
  - python39-sphinx
  - python39-sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml
  - python39-toml
  - python39-urllib3
  - rebase
  - rsync
  - run
  - sed
  - shared-mime-info
  - tar
  - terminfo
  - tzcode
  - tzdata
  - util-linux
  - vim-minimal
  - w32api-headers
  - w32api-runtime
  - which
  - windows-default-manifest
  - xkeyboard-config
  - xz
  - zlib0
  - zstd
  ```

Comment: Remove everything and just install what you actually need - base packages + gcc

Comment: Have you seen this install page? https://www.cygwin.com/install.html "Only the minimal base packages from the Cygwin distribution are installed by default, which takes up about 100 MB."

Comment: In addition to the good suggestion of David; to check how many packages you really installed `cygcheck -cd | wc -l`

Comment: Please do not format questions/answers like this - if there are that many bullets, please put them within a code box, which is scrollable and doesn't require 10+ page lengths of scrolling. Since everything was terminal output, please copy the terminal output exactly as it appears and paste within a code box